# Не работает before в под классе. css html

Tags: html, css

Возникла проблема.

Не работает before в под классе:

```css
.discount {
    color: #8e8e8e;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    padding: 2px 5px;
}
.discount.mine:before{
    content: '100';
    padding: 2px 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a class="seller"><span class="discount mine">100-900</span> 70-700 <span class="val">rub</span><a>
```

Пробовал разными способами, и не в какую не создается before.
Или это не возможно сделать?
Прошу вашу помощь!

Comment: Скорее всего вы применяете не к тому классу, ну т.е. опечатка.

Comment: Все вроде хорошо тогда когда я делаю вот так: `.discount:before {}`
А если вот так: .discount.mine:before {}` не чего не происходит. 
Вроде бы все правильно пишу.

Comment: Все, спасибо) Работает.
Ошибка была даже не знаю в чем. У меня включен Openserver, и поэтому иногда бывает так что не прогружается страница сайта. Например картинки, или даже вот как сейчас текст. Вроде бы просто я его перезапустил, у меня формат файла если что php. Думаю все было в этом.